# Need help binding data to Kivy Speedmeter

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, kivy, mavlink

I'm working on a "speedometer" project for my drone. It uses the Mavlink protocol to communicate with the drone utilizing the Mavlink mirror in Mission Planner. Basically, using Queue, the "listener is setup like this:

```
def listener(out_que):
    # from the mavlink.io page
    the_connection=mavutil.mavlink_connection('tcp:localhost:14550')
    the_connection.wait_heartbeat()

    while True:
        the_message=the_connection.recv_match(type='whatever mavlink msg',blocking=True).parameter
        out_que.put(the_message)
```

I can print the message out using:

```
que = queue.Queue()

threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(que,), daemon=True).start()

while True:
    
    value = que.get()

    print(value)
```

However, I am trying to use this data to update the value of a kivy Speedmeter. Ive tried this two ways:

```
que = queue.Queue()

threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(que,), daemon=True).start()

class MyApp(App):
    while True:
        value=que.get()
if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

The first way does not allow the speedmeter to load but the value variable is updating.

The second:

```
que = queue.Queue()

threading.Thread(target=listener, args=(que,), daemon=True).start()

class MyApp(App):
    
   value=que.get()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

This allows the speedmeter to load but will only update the value one time.

the .kv file looks like this:

```
SpeedMeter:
    value: app.value
```

My apologies for the newbie question , but how can i get this value to update or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Make sure the `value` variable is a Kivy `Property`. Perhaps a `NumericProperty`.

Comment: The value is an integer. I can get it to set the value once. It just wont update the value.

Comment: But is it a [NumericProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.0.0/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.NumericProperty)?